# How to automate Google Drive Docs OCR facility?

Tags: node.js, api, google-docs-api

I have using Google Drive and its Open with Google Docs facility to convert them into OCR word file (.docx). Because the word file preserves the formatting also. I have many images and upload them to Drive and convert them into editable one by one because PDF conversion does not work.

In this time I want to wait patiently to finish one conversion process. After that I start the next conversion, it is time consuming.

I used  Google OCR API. But it does not preserve the formatting such as bold, alignment, etc.

So, is there any way to automate this process using REST API?

**UPDATE**

1. Uploaded images to the Google Drive [image: link]
2. The Right click context menu of an image in Google Drive [image: link]
3. Google Docs in the context menu of "Open with" [image: link]
4. After the conversion process the OCR(Auto language detected) [image: link]
5. Finally the Google document and the image [image: link]

I tried the [googleapis](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) on GitHub and I selected the drive sample [list.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/drive/list.js) code.

**My Code**

```
'use strict';

const {google} = require('googleapis');
const sampleClient = require('../sampleclient');

const drive = google.drive({
  version: 'v3',
  auth: sampleClient.oAuth2Client,
});

async function runSample(query) {
  const params = {pageSize: 3};
  params.q = query;
  const res = await drive.files.list(params);
  console.log(res.data);
  return res.data;
}

if (module === require.main) {
  const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];
  sampleClient
    .authenticate(scopes)
    .then(runSample)
    .catch(console.error);
}

module.exports = {
  runSample,
  client: sampleClient.oAuth2Client,
};
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand your question, can I ask you about the result you want? You want to convert the images to Google Document. There are the images in your Google Drive. If my understanding is correct, how about converting by Drive API? Although I'm not sure about your images, in my environment, I could confirm that "bold", "text alignment" and "colors" are preserved. If this is not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Your imagination also correct. If you tried this in your drive, you can understand that. But I don't know if it's possible with Drive API. Unlike, the image to text OCR facility, converting to OCR by Google drive (Upload image to drive > Right click > open with Google docs) is better.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about your question from your reply. When I saw Google Documents by manually creating and Drive API, I think that both Google Document is the same. Of course, this can be achieved by googleapis of Node.js.

Comment: Is there anyway to fo this?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you provide a sample image you want to convert to Google Document?

Comment: The sample images are added see the above question, please

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to test the conversion in my environment, can you provide a sample image you want to convert to Google Document?

Comment: Thank you so much, Sure, here are the sample images for the testing : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1u83bhZwQG6CF-yaL8YvbKM2wDss5N1eC?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the sample images. I could test them. When Drive API is used, it seems that the result is the same with your sample result in your question. But I'm not sure whether this is the quality you want. By the way, can you provide your current script of Node.js? Before I think of the sample script, I would like to know about your method for requesting to Drive API. Do you use googleapis or others?

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing a sample script. From your reply and your script, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? In my environment, I could confirm that the modified script worked. But if it didn't work when you run it, I apologize. At that time, please check the quickstart, again.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is your huge support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

From your sample script, it was found that you are using `googleapis`. So in this modification, I also used `googleapis`. The image files in Drive are converted to Google Document with OCR by `files.copy` method in Drive API. The following modification supposes the following points.

1. You are using `googleapis` in Node.js.
2. When you run your script, you have already retrieved file list by Drive API.

   - This indicates that `drive` in your script can be also used for the `files.copy` method.

#### Notes :

- If you have not used Drive API yet, please check [the quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs). (version 3).

#### Confirmation point:

Before you run the script, please confirm the following points.

- In order to use the `files.copy` method, please include `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` to the scopes in `if` statement in `list.js`.

#### Modified script 1 (to convert Google Docs with OCR by giving files() id:

In this modification, `runSample()` was modified.

```
function runSample()
{
    // Please set the file(s) IDs of sample images in Google Drive.
    const files = [
        "### fileId1 ###",
        "### fileId2 ###",
        "### fileId3 ###", , ,
    ];

    // takes each file and convert them to Google Docs format
    files.forEach((id) =>
    {
        const params = {
            fileId: id,
            resource:
            {
                mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.document',
                parents: ['### folderId ###'], // If you want to put the converted files in a specific folder, please use this.
            },
            fields: 'id',
        };

        // Convert after processes here
        // Here we copy the IDs 
        drive.files.copy(params, (err, res) =>
        {
            if (err)
            {
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log(res.data.id);
        });
    });
}
```

#### Note:

- Your files(images) are converted to Google Document by above script, and it seems that the result (Google document) is same as your sample (in your question). But I'm not sure whether this is the quality which you want, please apologize.

#### References:

- [Node.js Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs)
- [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy)
- [Mimetypes](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types)

#### Modified script 2 (to convert Google Docs with OCR by single folder and selects only images:

- You want to convert the files(images) to Google Document by retrieving them  from a specific folder.
- You want to retrieve files of `image/png`, `image/jpeg` and `image/tiff`.

#### Sample code syntax:

```
const folderId = "### folderId ###"; // Please set the folder ID including the images.
drive.files.list(
{
    pageSize: 1000,
    q: `'${folderId}' in parents and (mimeType='image/png' or mimeType='image/jpeg' or mimeType='image/tiff')`,
    fields: 'files(id)',
}, (err, res) =>
{
    if (err)
    {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    const files = res.data.files;
    files.forEach((file) =>
    {
        console.log(file.id);

        // Please put above script of the files.forEach method by modifying ``id`` to ``file.id``.

    });
});
```

In this next modification, entire `runSample()` was modified.

```
function runSample()
{
    // Put the folder ID including files you want to convert.
    const folderId = "### folderId ###";

    // Retrieve file list.
    drive.files.list(
    {
        pageSize: 1000,
        q: `'${folderId}' in parents and (mimeType='image/png' or mimeType='image/jpeg' or mimeType='image/tiff')`,
        fields: 'files(id)',
    }, (err, res) =>
    {
        if (err)
        {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        const files = res.data.files;

        // Retrieve each file from the retrieved file list.
        files.forEach((file) =>
        {
            const params = {
                fileId: file.id,
                resource:
                {
                    mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.document',
                    parents: ['### folderId ###'],
                },
                fields: 'id',
            };

            // Convert a file
            drive.files.copy(params, (err, res) =>
            {
                if (err)
                {
                    console.error(err);
                    return;
                }
                console.log(res.data.id);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

#### References:

- [Files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Image MiMe types](https://github.com/google/google-drive-proxy/blob/master/DriveProxy/API/MimeType.cs)

Comment: In some cases, when there are more images, this process skips some of them. If I upload 10 images sometimes it only converts about 7 images and 3 skips. So, how can I omit this skips?

Comment: @S.Sakthybaalan Thank you for your comment. I think that the situation of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will post it as a new question.

Comment: Can you, please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58888813/unable-to-create-googledrive-folder-after-1-hour-refresh-token-doesnot-work

Comment: @S.Sakthybaalan I saw it. But unfortunately, I cannot propose the clear solution of it. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.