# Google APIs RefreshToken does not work for Google Drive

Tags: php, laravel-5, google-drive-api

I want to create a folder in Google Drive while clicking the button in the Laravel project. I am following this tutorial
[API Keys](http://www.howtosolvenow.com/how-to-create-your-google-drive-api-keys/),
[Refresh Token](http://www.howtosolvenow.com/how-to-get-refresh-token-for-google-drive-api/)

The following code is working fine. But after 1 hour(3600 seconds) I am unable to create the folder and I am getting the following error.

```
{
    "status": "Order not updated",
    "msg": "{\n \"error\": {\n  \"errors\": [\n   {\n    \"domain\": \"global\",\n    \"reason\": \"authError\",\n    \"message\": \"Invalid Credentials\",\n    \"locationType\": \"header\",\n    \"location\": \"Authorization\"\n   }\n  ],\n  \"code\": 401,\n  \"message\": \"Invalid Credentials\"\n }\n}\n",
    "is_success": false
}
```

So, then I want to create the access token again manually then update it here.
The code as follows

**GooGleDriveController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Exception;
use Google_Client;
use Google_Service_Drive;
use Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Order;
use App\Enums\GoogleDriveEnum;

class GoogleDriveController extends Controller
{
    private $drive;

    public function getDrive($id)
    {
        try
        {
            $order=Order::find($id);
            $client = new Google_Client();
            $client->setClientId(GoogleDriveEnum::getValue('CLIENT_ID'));
            $client->setClientSecret(GoogleDriveEnum::getValue('CLIENT_SECRET'));
            $client->setRedirectUri(GoogleDriveEnum::getValue('REDIRECT'));
            $client->addScope(GoogleDriveEnum::getValue('SCOPE'));
            $client->setAccessToken(GoogleDriveEnum::getValue('ACCESSTOKEN'));
            $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
            $client->setApprovalPrompt("consent"); //none || consent || select_account
            $client->setAccessType("offline");
            $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

            $code="my_code_is_here";
            $refreshToken="my_refresh_token_is_here";
            // $client->authenticate($code);

            $tokens = $client->GetAccessToken(GoogleDriveEnum::getValue('CLIENT_ID'), GoogleDriveEnum::getValue('REDIRECT'), GoogleDriveEnum::getValue('CLIENT_SECRET'), $code);
            $client->setAccessToken($tokens["access_token"]);
            $this->drive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

            $folder_meta = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
                'name' => $order->code,
                'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'));
            $folder = $this->drive->files->create($folder_meta, array(
                'fields' => 'id'));
            $order->google_drive_link = "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/".$folder->id;
            $order->save();

            $response["msg"] = "Folder has been successfully created";
            $response["status"] = "Success";
            $response["is_success"] = true;
            return response()->json($response);

        }catch(\Exception $th)
        {
            $response["status"] = "Folder not created";
            $response["msg"] = $th->getMessage();
            $response["is_success"] = false;
            return response()->json($response);
        }
    }
}
```

**GoogleDriveEnum.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Enums;

use BenSampo\Enum\Enum;

final class GoogleDriveEnum extends Enum
{
    const CLIENT_ID = 'my_client_id';
    const CLIENT_SECRET = 'my_client_secret';
    const REDIRECT = 'https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground';
    const SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
    const ACCESSTOKEN = 'my_access_token';
    const REFRESHTOKEN = 'my_refresh_token';
    const CODE = 'my_code';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you implement the PHP quickstart [1] into your code using the credentials.json file. With the access token you can update the refresh token everytime that expires (3600s), it's a better aproach:

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
    if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    } else {
        // Request authorization from the user.
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
        print 'Enter verification code: ';
        $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

        // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
        $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

        // Check to see if there was an error.
        if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
            throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
        }
    }
    // Save the token to a file.
    if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
        mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php

Comment: It shows `Undefined index: expires_in` and I want to access offline. Not to open browser to authorize.

Comment: With the manual way you're using you still need to open a browser to get the token. If you implement the quickstart completely you'll have to open the browser only the first time to get the token, after that the token will be refreshed when it's about to expire.

Comment: So first time it requires from browser, then no need to login again, correct?

Comment: Exactly, it'll use the downloaded token.json to refresh the access token. At least you later add more scopes, for which you'll need to delete the token.json, run the code again and this will prompt you the consent screen (login) to create a new token.json with the new scopes you need.

Comment: You could also check [services accounts](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-service-accounts), which you can use to make API calls without authenticating.

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/docs/oauth-server.md#creating-a-service-account

Comment: If it helped you, please consider accepting the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)