How to convert image to google doc using google drive api V3 in python?
I have several png images in my google drive. I want to do OCR on these images to get the text with my ocrLanguage. I have followed this code:
https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/8c808bf8c060455fe5401ecacad07b94
With this code, one can 'upload' an image. That image gets converted to google document and that document is exported to a text file. This works fine; however I do not want this, as my images are already in my drive folder.
I want to convert the image to a google doc with ocrLanguage mentioned and then export that to text file. I could not find any example for this. (I did try changing the above code to copy the image to doc ... however it requires media and some other details... which I did not know how to supply.)
Please help and suggest or point me to any working example.
As my application is in python, I am looking for a solution in Python.
Thanks

No response at all? Is there any error on my part here?

Found some clue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55554372/1940163 ... and it worked.
I had to search internet for 6 days and required about 2 hours to understand how to use this method to python api. Thanks to all for your time.
